# Don't understand working out for phasor of output voltage

Tags: phasor

We had a question in class which the teacher was working out about phasors but i can't understand the last two parts of the working out. why did he suddenly change the angle into a negative value and divide the amplitude by root 2? Vs is 10.[image]

Comment: i found out that he divided by root 2 to get an RMS value, but the question only asked to find the output voltage from a sine wave voltage source. So i was wondering, is it always necessary to convert the phasor into an RMS value and does that also involve changing the sign of the angle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sign of the angle changed because it went from denominator to the numerator. That's what [taking the inverse of the imaginary unit does](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Fi).

You can see that more clearly if you just [invert the complex number](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%281%2B0.094i%29) from your first equation:

[image]

If Vs=10 as you say, then that derivation is incorrect between the 2nd and 3rd line though, [becuase](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10%2F%281%2B0.094i%29) the 2nd line does not equal the 3rd, instead you get 9.956 as the radius/magnitude:

[image]

So I suspect Vs is actually \$\frac{10}{\sqrt{2}}\$ or there was some mistake (either on his part in deriving/explaining or when you transcribed it).